# How to install only Wolfram Kernel and register to a MathLM Server?

Tags: kernel, python, installation

I have access to a MathLM server and the Mathematica 11.3 install files.  Is there a command line option for the install that will only install the Wolfram Kernel and not the Mathematica front-end?

Once installed how do I register the kernel to the MathML server without the front-end?

I am attempting to experiment with the [Wolfram Client For Python](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframClientForPython). Since it does not appear to need the front-end I would like to setup the environment without it.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @RolfMertig I have access to Windows 10 or Windows 8.1